# How can I display an output from an web api in a spinner

Tags: c#, android, api, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have this,

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Error fetching data. Server returned status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var content = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    dynamic arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);

                    foreach (dynamic obj in arr)
                    {
                        tvJobID.Text = obj.JobID;
                        tvJobType.Text = obj.JobType;
                    }
                }
            }
```

But now I want to display the JobTypes returned from the API in a spinner,

Spinner mySpinner= FindViewById(Resource.Id.listSpinner);

I tired everything. No luck so far, any help is highly appreciated

my var content looks like this

```
{"JobTypesGroup": "Leak"},{"JobTypesGroup": "Service"},{"JobTypesGroup": "Installation"},{"JobTypesGroup": "Miscellaneous"}]}
```

I want to convert this to a list and get the JobTypesGroup in the spinner

Comment: You can create an array list of types and render via setting adapter in your spinner. This might help you https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/

Comment: @Tasneem but the problem is I can't do this,  List<string> list = new List<string>(content); it's giving me error "cannot convert from string to int".

Comment: Seems like your type is integer type , List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>() ;  and in for loop list.add(obj.JobType) ; You can not create object of List<> in JAVA as its an interface.

Comment: Hi @Tasneem I'm using C#

Comment: Hi @Tasneem I'm using C#. I edited my question. could you please have a look. Thanks

Comment: I have never worked with C# though , let me figure out if I can find something for you.

Comment: @Tasneem thank you very much. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about C# but in JAVA you can create a local List(List of job types) and give it to a spinner as a data.

List is very useful abstract class of Collection Framework in JAVA.

Similar thing you can find in C#